# Can't "except" category in Posts controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table with ID, Category_id, title, etc...
I need to output every category except nr. "10"

I already outputted only category_id = 10, but don't know how to output others except category 10.

Here is controller:

```
public function index()
{   
    $sponsored = Raksti::where('category_id', '10')->get();
    $kat = RakstuKategorijas::all();
    $raksts = Raksti::all();
    $raksti = collect($raksts)->except('category_id', '10');

    return view('home',[
        'sponsored' => $sponsored,
        'kat' => $kat,
        'raksti' => $raksti,
    ]);
}
```

I don't get any errors - code output all posts including category 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
public function index()
{   
    $sponsored = Raksti::where('category_id', '10')->get();
    $kat = RakstuKategorijas::all();
    $raksti = Raksti::where('category_id', '<>', '10')->get();

    return view('home',[
        'sponsored' => $sponsored,
        'kat' => $kat,
        'raksti' => $raksti,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Wow! That works fine. So i guess that second parameter "<>" is like "except"? Didnt saw anywhere this kind a solution. Thx a lot!

Comment: @KarlisPokkers '<>' is SQL for '!='. What you are doing here is you are getting all the results `where caregory_id != 10`. If you pass 3 parameters to a `where clause`, the 2nd one is the operator which is run against both sides. This solution is better than `except`, because when using `except`, you are getting all results, then removing some, while here you take all results that you need and you do not get results you will not need.

Comment: @KarlisPokkers If this answer solves your problem, please consider accepting it, so other people, who have similar issues might see it works and it might help them.

Comment: You solved my problem and also give me a good explanation about this. Thank you a lot good Sir :)

Answer (score 0):

simple change two methods are the Eloquent - where not equal to

Method 1:

```
$raksti = Raksti::where('category_id', '!=', '10')->get();
```

Method 2:

```
$raksti = Raksti::where('category_id', '<>', '10')->get();
```